# Python Django multiple request parameters

Tags: python, django

I am new to python & django and am trying to build a simple web application. I am running into the below issue

I am passing the following code

```
def view(request, cases_id, transactions_id):
    item = Cases.objects.get(pk=cases_id)
    item2 = Transactions.objects.get(pk=transactions_id)
    return render(request, 'view.html', {'item': item, 'item2': item2})
```

and getting the following error:

```
view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'transactions_id'
```

My `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'), 
    path('new', views.new, name='new'),
    path('edit', views.edit, name='edit'),
    path('view/<cases_id>',views.view, name='view'),
]
```

Comment: Please share your `urls.py`.

Comment: from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.home, name='home'),
   path('new', views.new, name='new'),
   path('edit', views.edit, name='edit'),
   path('view/<cases_id>',views.view, name='view'),
   ]

Comment: So, what is unclear about the error? Your URL only sends cases_id. Where is the value for transactions_id supposed to be coming from?

Comment: sorry I am new to this. How do I pass both values in the url section?

Comment: `path('view/<cases_id>/<transaction_id>',views.view, name='view'),`

Answer (score 1):

I think Marat has the solution in the comments above.
Just update your path to include the `transaction_id` variable.

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views 
urlpatterns = [
    path('view/<cases_id>/<transaction_id>',views.view, name='view'),
    #                     ^^^^ Add this bit here
]
```

You could also handle this particular error by adding a default value to your view method.

```
def view(request, cases_id, transactions_id=0):
    ...
```

This way, if no transaction_id is present in the URL, the method will have a default value to use. You can replace `0` with whatever value makes the most sense for your application.